# NSButton state management

Tags: swift, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

My `NSButton` is using custom `NSButtonCell` class, which in turn is overriding `drawBezel`:

```
override func drawBezel(withFrame frame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        let path = NSBezierPath(bound: frame.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(NumKeypadConstants.buttonInset), dy: CGFloat(NumKeypadConstants.buttonInset)), withCorners: corners, withRadius: CGFloat(NumKeypadConstants.cornerRadius), flip: flipIt)

        path.lineWidth = NumKeypadConstants.borderWidth
        if(isEnabled)
        {
            if(isHighlighted)
            {
                let fillColor: NSColor = NumKeypadConstants.buttonHighlightColor
                let strokeColor: NSColor = NumKeypadConstants.buttonBorderColor
                fillColor.setFill()
                strokeColor.setStroke()
                path.fill()
                path.stroke()
            }
            else
            {
                if(state == .on)
                {
                    let fillColor: NSColor = NumKeypadConstants.buttonOnColor
                    let strokeColor: NSColor = NumKeypadConstants.buttonBorderColor
                    fillColor.setFill()
                    strokeColor.setStroke()
                    path.fill()
                    path.stroke()
                }
                else
                {
                    let fillColor: NSColor = NumKeypadConstants.buttonBackgroundColor
                    let strokeColor: NSColor = NumKeypadConstants.buttonBorderColor
                    fillColor.setFill()
                    strokeColor.setStroke()
                    path.fill()
                    path.stroke()
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            let fillColor: NSColor = NumKeypadConstants.buttonBackgroundDisabledColor
            let strokeColor: NSColor = NumKeypadConstants.buttonBorderColor
            fillColor.setFill()
            strokeColor.setStroke()
            path.fill()
            path.stroke()
        }
    }
```

Now my button supports both types 1) `.momentaryChange` 2) `.pushOnPushOff`. I was expecting that depending on button types, the state will be altered or not. But no matter what I set using `setButtonType`, the .state member of cell is always changing on button press.

Do I understand correct, that it is my responsibility to check the type of button and either regard or disregard `.state`? Could it be that certain combination of `bezelStyle` and button type will tell the cell to internally ignore `.state` when using momentary types?

If I have to check for the button type, then how I check for the type in `NSButtonCell`? The type is not passed to it. Should I create own property and pass type?

Comment: See the [discussion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbuttoncell/1527474-setbuttontype?language=objc) of `setButtonType:`

Comment: `showsStateBy` is 0 when button is momentary and `changeGrayCellMask, changeBackgroundCellMask` if pushOnPushOff. Should I just check for these 2 bits and if not set, ignore `state`? To be honest I don't understand how those masks are related to state.

Comment: If `showsStateBy` is 0 then the button doesn't show or change state and is a momentary type.